# How can I explicitly set specific timezone in vuejs-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, vuejs-datepicker

I am using [vuejs-Datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker?tab=readme-ov-file#usage). How can I set the timezone to America/New_York?
I want the widget to display the date and time in the New York timezone, regardless of where the user is. I have looked through the documentation but could not find any settings for this.
To elaborate, if a user in China visits the website at midnight, the date should be yesterday.